# Most members of the product topology are not products

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

My textbook which is an introductory course on metric spaces mentions the following about product topology:

**Definition** : Suppose $n \in \mathbb N,$ and for  $i=1,\dots,n,$ $(X_i, \tau_i)$ is a metric space. The collection of all unions of products $\Pi_{i=1}^n U_i,$ where each $U_i$ is open in $X_i,$ is called the product topology on $\Pi_{i=1}^n X_i.$ Any metric that generates the product topology is called a product metric on $\Pi_{i=1}^n X_i$.

**The following statements are a bit not clear to me. Will be grateful if you could give me some clarity**

> Subsets of products are not usually products. The Subset $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ for example is not a product. Members of the product topology can all be expressed as union of products, but most members of the product topology are not products.
>
> For example - the open disc $U=\{x \in \mathbb R^2~|~x_1^2+x_2^2 <1 \}$ is a member of the product topology on $\mathbb R^2$ but it is not a product of open intervals of $\mathbb R$. Infact, to express it as  a union of products of open intervals, we need to use an infinite collection of such products in the following way:
> For each $x \in U$, set $r_x=1- \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$. Then $U$ can be expressed as the union $$\bigcup \{(x_1-r_x~,~ x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x~,~ x_2+r_x)~|~x \in U\}$$

How is the open disc a member of the product topology on $\mathbb R^2$

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: (1) The argument shows that the disc is an element of the product topology, since as you said it is a union of products of open sets of the factors. They didn't really prove that is it not itself a product of open sets of the factors, but that is rather easy.

Comment: (2) I think that the bit on subsets is only extra info.

Comment: Products of intervals, for example, are rectangles with sides parallel to the axis. Circles are no such things.

Comment: I think this is nothing more than a clarification.  A person hearing "The Glafamodorian Topology" might naively assume that all the open sets are Glafamodorian, but as it turns because the union of Glafamodorian sets don't have to be Glafamorian, most of the open sets are sets that *aren't* Glafamodorian, but *unions* and *intersections* of Glafamodorian sets.  That's all it is saying.

Comment: I edited the definition to make it clearer (I hope).

Comment: I think that confusing part of the  question is, "...but **most** members of the product topology are not products." In what sense exactly the word "most" is used is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The example illustrates how "un-product-like" an element of the product topology can be. It just says that $D^2$ is not a product of any intervals, but can be expressed as the *union* of products, rather than products of open sets (which heuristically look like boxes.

The subset $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is also not a product, it is the union of the basis vectors on the $x,y$ axes. A product should like like the cartesian product of two sets. For example $(0,1)$ is indeed a product: $\{0\} \times (0,1)$ although it is not open in the product topology.

The author is maybe making complicated a clarification that elements of the product topology need not be products themselves, since subsets more generally are not products.

---

I also cannot resist the temptation to say that the box to disk method here also allows us to pass from elements in the basis of the product topology and open disks (with some technical details) which hints that the euclidian (open disks) topology and product topology coincide for $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: You may want to change $\{(0,1),(0,1)\}$ to $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$.

Comment: @timon92 thanks

Comment: Could you please explain why the open disc is a member of the product topology

Comment: @MathMan: Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Can you prove that this function is continuous? If so then what is $f^{-1}(-\infty, 1)$? What is the relation between $U$ (as in your question) and $f^{-1}(-\infty, 1)$? Can you conclude from there that $U$ is open?

Answer (score 2):

Think (old-school) Lego, where every piece is a rectangular (3-D) block. Those are your "products", i.e. basis elements. You can snap together (i.e. take a union of) a bunch of them to make shapes, and while you can make a shape that is just a bigger block (i.e. product), most of the shapes you make will not look like blocks, i.e. won't be a product.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the exposition you are reading is to make the point that not every open set in the product topology on $X_1\times\dots\times X_n$ is of the form $U_1\times \dots \times U_n$ where $U_i$ is open in $X_i$.

The examples they give are $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ with the product topology and the sets $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$, and $U = \{(x,y) : \|(x,y)\| < 1\}$. The set $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is a subset of $(-1,2)\times(-1,2)$ which is an element of the product topology, but it is not itself a product of open sets $U_1\times U_2$ where $U_1,U_2$ are open in $\Bbb R$. Likewise for the set $B$. It is a union of products of open sets in $\Bbb R$, but it is not itself a product open set.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Since the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$ is a product metric, doesn't it mean that every open set in $\mathbb R \ times \mathbb R$ is of the form $U_1 \times U_2$. Also, can't we express the sub set $\{(0,1)~(1,0)\}$ as  $\{(0,1)~\times (1,0)\}$ a product of two open sets? Thanks again!

Comment: @MathMan You are confused about what the notation $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ means here. In this case, $(0,1)$ is the ordered pair whose first coordinate is $0$ and whose second coordinate is $1$. Any finite collection of points is certainly not open in the product topology, forget about being a product of open sets in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: okay.. so, what the author intends to say is that most members of product topology are not products of open sets. Is that correct?

Comment: @MathMan yes that’s correct

Answer (score 1):

Here is the main idea in the proof you ask about: Let $U$ denote the open unit disc in $\mathbb R^2.$

Claim: For each $x\in U,$ there exists an open square $S(x)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $x\in S(x)\subset U.$ Let's accept this result for the moment.

I should be careful to say that by "square" I mean a square with sides parallel to the axes. Such a square can be written as $I\times J,$ where $I,J$ are bounded open subintervals of $\mathbb R$ with the same length. Of course $S(x)$ depends heavily on $x;$ it necessarily gets smaller as $x$ gets close to $\partial U.$

We then have

$$\tag 1 U = \bigcup_{x\in U}S(x).$$

Why? Let $x_0\in U.$ Then $x_0\in S(x_0),$ and $S(x_0)$ is contained in the union on the right. Thus the left of $(1)$ is contained in the right side. On the other hand, each $S(x)$ on the right is contained in $U,$ hence so is the union of all of them. Thus the right side of $(1)$ is contained in the left side. This gives the desired equality.

Because each $S(x)$ is the product of open intervals, it is open in the product topology, hence so is the union of any collection of them. We conclude from $(1)$ that $U$ is open in the product topology.

It remains to prove the claim. Define $D(x,r)$ to be the open disc centered at $x$ of radius $r.$ Suppose $x\in U.$ Then the distance from $x$ to $\partial U$ is $1-|x|.$ It follows that $D(x,1-|x|)\subset U.$ Next, observe that $(-1/2,1/2)\times (-1/2,1/2)$ is contained in $U.$ Stare at that picture a bit to see that more generally, given $x\in U,$ and $r_x=(1-|x),$ we have

$$S(x,r_x) =(x_1-r_x/2,x_2+r_x/2)\times (x_2-r_x/2,x_2+r_x/2)\subset D(x,r_x).$$

So to prove the claim, we start with $x\in U,$ go to $D(x,r_x)$ then to $S(x,r_x).$ This $S(x,r_x)$ is the $S(x)$ mentioned in the claim.

PS: The proof in the shaded area in your question is not quite right. In the final union, $r_x$ doesn't work, but $r_x/2$ does work, as indicated above.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ were a product, say $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}=A\times B$ where $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $B\subseteq \Bbb R$. Then, since $(0,1)\in A\times B$ we must have that $0\in A$ and $1\in B$. Similarly, since$(1,0)\in A\times B$ we must have that $1\in A$ and $0\in B$. But then, since $1\in A$ and $1\in B$ we would have that $(1,1)\in A\times B = \{(0,1), (1,0)\}$, 
a contradiction which shows that $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ cannot be of the form $A\times B$ for any choice of $A$ and $B$. That is, $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is not "a product".

Similarly, suppose the set $U=\{x \in \mathbb R^2|x_1^2+x_2^2 <1 \}$ were a product $A\times B$ (where $x=(x_1,x_2)$ for each $x$). 
Then since $(\frac89,0)\in U$ we must have $\frac89\in A$. Similarly, since $(0,\frac89)\in U$ we must have $\frac89\in B$. Then it would follow that $(\frac89,\frac89)\in A\times B = U$, but $(\frac89)^2+(\frac89)^2=\frac{128}{81}>1$, hence $(\frac89,\frac89)\not\in U$. Thus $U$ cannot be a product, i.e. it cannot be of the form $A\times B$ for any $A$ and $B$.

(It is another matter that each of $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ and $U$ is *homeomorphic* to a product, so in a certain more general interpretation it is a product, but the author didn't mean that, obviously. For now you probably need not worry about homeomorphisms, in this context.)

Finally, each $(x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)$ is a product $A\times B$ where $A$ is the interval $(x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x)$ and $B$ is the interval 
$(x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)$. Let $V=\bigcup \{(x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)|x \in U\}$. Clearly $V$ is, by its definition, the *union of* products. What the author says (or meant, I assume) is that $U=V$, so $U$ is the union of products. To show that $V=U$, you need to show that $U\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq U$. To show that $U\subseteq V$ notice that if $(x_1,x_2)\in U$ then 
$(x_1,x_2)\in (x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x) \subseteq V$ (so the inclusion $U\subseteq V$ is easy, or trivial). To show that $V\subseteq U$ you need to show that $(x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)\subseteq U$ for each $x=(x_1,x_2)\in U$. Here you would likely be expected to use the condition that $r_x=1- \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$. But, either the author messed up, or you didn't copy the text from the book correctly, and the condition $V\subseteq U$ does not hold. Indeed, take $x=(x_1,x_2)=(\frac36,\frac46)$. Then $x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{25}{36}<1$, 
so $x\in U$. We have that $r_x=1-\frac56=\frac16$. But $(x_1+r_x)^2+(x_2+r_x)^2=\frac{41}{36}>1$, and by continuity there is some positive $r<r_x$ such that $(x_1+r)^2+(x_2+r)^2>1$ showing that $(x_1+r,x_2+r)\in (x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)\subseteq V$ yet $(x_1+r,x_2+r)\not\in U$, so $V\not\subseteq U$. (If you prefer to avoid the use of continuity, then you may take $r=\frac17<r_x$ for example, and let  $(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+r,x_2+r)=(\frac{27}{42},\frac{34}{42})$ and notice that $(y_1,y_2)\in (x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)\subseteq V$, yet 
$(y_1,y_2)\not\in U$ since $(y_1)^2+(y_2)^2=\frac{1885}{1764}>1$.) 
If the book doesn't have it right, then you might try to find how to better define $r_x$ so that you end up with $(x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)\subseteq U$ (and therefore $V\subseteq U$ and $V=U$, showing that $U$ is the union of products). A picture might help, in fact each product $(x_1-r_x,x_1+r_x) \times (x_2-r_x,x_2+r_x)$ is a square with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, and with "center" $x=(x_1,x_2)$ (=the intersection of the diagonals of this square). For each $x\in U$ you could certainly find (or draw) a small square around $x$ that is contained in $U$, and then $U$ is the union of all such squares, showing that $U$ is the union of "products".

The open disc $U$ in the plane is not a product. But any subset of the product space (i.e. a subset of the plane $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$) is, by definition, open, provided that it is *the union* of products of open sets, and $U$ is indeed such a union, therefore $U$ is open, therefore $U$ is a member of the product topology. This does not say that $U$ is a product! It just illustrates that the *product topology* consists of sets each of which is *the union* of products of open sets. Thank you for the interesting question.