# Example of a Subset of R X R that is not of the Form A X B

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

What would be an example of a subset $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ that is not of the form $A\times B$, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Any guidance as to understanding what this question is asking, and an example of such a subset would be great.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2544727 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3226526

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you don't understand. Do you know what $\bf R$ stands for? do you know what $A\times B$ means?

Comment: A circle .......

Comment: I do understand what all the terms mean. So would anything with a curve qualify, since the Cartesian product is always a rectangular region?

Comment: Most curves will do, but I like small examples. This question admits examples consisting of just two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is such an example.

Also the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ e.g.

If $F=A \times B$, then $(0,0),(1,1) \in F \to 0 \in A, 1 \in B \to (0,1) \in A \times B$, but $(0,1) \notin F$, etc. Similar arguments apply to the circle.